Vite cannot find manifest in Laravel Herd with Kaspersky Endpoint Security installed on Windows
I'm working on a Laravel project using Laravel Herd on Windows, and I'm facing an issue after the company installed Kaspersky Endpoint Security on my machine. When I run npm run dev, Vite sometimes struggles to find the manifest file, leading to page loading errors. While it works intermittently, it's very slow and produces minor errors.

Observations:
Vite occasionally cannot locate the manifest file, causing the page not to load correctly.
It works very slowly or with errors, though sometimes it works, but inconsistently.
I cannot disable or modify Kaspersky Endpoint Security settings due to company policy and lack of admin permissions.
What I've Tried:
Restarting the development server (npm run dev).
Clearing Vite's cache.
Ensuring that all dependencies are up to date.
Question:
Has anyone experienced similar issues with Kaspersky Endpoint Security interfering with Vite and Laravel Herd on Windows? Is there any configuration or workaround to ensure Vite works properly without disabling Kaspersky or modifying its settings?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you in advance.
